# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active at session.beginTransaction()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-transactions

I am new to hibernate and got a task to migrate code written in hibernate 3 to hibernate 5. While debugging, I am getting the error - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active and this happening over the method - beginTransaction(). I have checked numerous ways in online but unable to correct the error. Below is the function written where this error is caused.

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public String callStoredProc(List<UniqueNoRidVo> uniqueNoRidVoMap) throws DBException {

    List<UniqueNoRidVo> uniqueNo = null;
    String return_value = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    int count = 0;

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    
    
    try{
        //Deleting old records from Temp table
        LOG.info("IN callStoredProc -START");
        String query = "delete from UniqueNoRidVo";
        session.createQuery(query).executeUpdate();

        LOG.info("Old records deleted from TEMP Table");

        //Inserting New RIDs into Temp table
        if(!uniqueNoRidVoMap.isEmpty()){
            tx = session.beginTransaction(); //Error code
            
            for(LiqVO vo : uniqueNoRidVoMap){
                session.saveOrUpdate(vo);
                if (++count % 50 == 0) {
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
            }
            session.flush();
            LOG.info("New RIDs inserted into TEMP table");

        }
        //Calling Stored procedure to generate Unique Nos.
        LOG.info("Calling Stored Procedure");
        tx=session.getTransaction();
        System.out.println("Calling Stored Procedure");
        //migrated to hibernate 5
        //SessionFactory sessionFactory=session.getSessionFactory();
        ConnectionProvider 
          connectionProvider=liqSessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().
            getServiceRegistry().getService(ConnectionProvider.class);
        Connection connection=connectionProvider.getConnection();
        CallableStatement st  = connection.prepareCall("{ call SP_FETCH_UQNO(?) }");
        
    //  CallableStatement st = session.connection().prepareCall("{ call SP_FETCH_UQNO(?) }");
        st.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        int abc = st.executeUpdate();

        LOG.info("abc output"+abc);
        if(abc>0) {
            return_value = st.getString(1);
        }
        LOG.info("Stored Procedure call completed: return_value "+ return_value);
        System.out.println("Stored Procedure call completed: return_value "+ return_value); 
        
    }catch(HibernateException hbex){
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
            LOG.error(hbex.toString());
            System.out.println("GD004-Error occurred in getting Unique Numbers for RID"+ 
           hbex.toString());
            throw new DBException("GD004-Error occurred in getting Unique Numbers for RID", 
       hbex.toString());
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqex) {
        LOG.error(sqex.toString());
        throw new DBException("GD005-Error occurred in getting Unique Numbers for RID", 
      sqex.toString());
    }
    
    return return_value;

}
```

Any advice appreciated on how to fix this, thank you!

Comment: What do you think `@Transactional` does?

Comment: It is spring transaction manager that the framework provides to perform database operations - insert/update and as the method is performing such operation, the attribute is set as readOnly = false. This is what I understand that is happening in this piece of code. I even tried moving beginTransaction() at the beginning of the method before performing any DB operation but still the code breaks at beginTransaction().

Comment: It already starts a transaction. You are basically figthing with that. Remove the start/commit/rollback stuff from the method.

Answer (score 0):

instead of explicitly opening the transaction you could allow the framework to handle the transaction ,in spring you can use the @transactional.

1. you could even check whether the transaction is still active using the tr.isActive() method

Ideally There is no need to do anything with Transaction, because it is handled by Spring.

For example:

Case 1: Transaction handled by Spring

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
...
return;
```

case 2: Transaction handled by yourself

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transcation tr = session.beginTransaction();
...
tr.commit();
session.close();
return;
```

Comment: As suggested I removed the commit/beginTransaction/rollback/close() and now I am not getting the error but as it tries to execute the procedure -st.executeUpdate();, the process hangs with no progress, am I missing something? Edited: The procedure runs fine via sql developer.

Comment: What is the exception ? can u pls paste it here ?

Comment: There is no exceptions, it hangs on executeUpdate() and does not procced to next statement. I had to manually kill the debugging. The method first deletes and inserts record in temp table and then proceeds to run the procedure. But if I select the temp table, I do not see the record changes being reflected before the procedure run. Does it not commit these records into the table before processing the procedure?